# jQuery plugin custom events

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a jQuery plugin that allows a user to select cells in a table, I've called this plugin cellSelect. cellSelect has 2 options:

```
$('table#tableid').cellSelect({
    select: function(){
       // Run when a cell is selected
    },
    deselect: function(){
       // Run when a cell is deselected
    }
});
```

I need create an event that can be run like this:

```
$('td').eq(15).select();
$('td').eq(15).deselect();
```

This will also run the functions specified in the plugin options

Answer (score 0):

In your plugin code you have to attach handler for select/deselect events so that whenever any select/deselect event is triggered on any cell it will execute the handler that is passed to `select` or `deselect` events.

Comment: you mean like this `$(this).bind('select', function(){
    
    options.selected;
    
   });
`